# Call activation hook multiple times

Tags: plugin-development, hooks, activation

I have a plugin that does some initialization stuff using `register_activation_hook` called from its `__construct()`.

I've since extended my plugin to add functionality to it. For the sake of organization, I've moved the extended functions to it's own class. I need to create a table that will deal with data unique to this new class.

My new class is instantiated from the construct of my main plugin.  And from the `construct` of my new class, I am trying to call `register_activation_hook` a second time to create my table.  Not surprisingly, this does not seem to work. (I have tested my db creation code elsewhere and it does work).

Is there a way that I can hook into the `register_activation_hook` from my new class to ensure the database is created at activation, or maybe even piggyback onto the parent class somehow to make sure the db is created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use some kind of a Controller and combine the calls to both classes in *one* callback for each action. The controller should be responsible for the real assignation of business logic to an event (action), not some code outside of your classes.
The basic point is: Your plugin controller should not alter data, only Models should do that.

The following example shows how to create a table (I use an option here to keep things simple) and an option:

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
namespace WPSE;
/**
 * Plugin Name: Multiple De/Activation Objects
 */

\register_activation_hook(
    __FILE__,
    array ( Front_Controller::get_instance(), 'activate' )
);

\register_deactivation_hook(
    __FILE__,
    array ( Front_Controller::get_instance(), 'deactivate' )
);

class Front_Controller
{
    protected static $instance = NULL;

    protected $db_name     = 'wpse_db';
    protected $option_name = 'wpse_option';

    public static function get_instance()
    {
        if ( NULL === self::$instance )
            self::$instance = new self;

        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function activate()
    {
        $db = new Db( $this->db_name );
        $db->create_table();

        $option = new Option( $this->option_name );
        $option->add();
    }

    public function deactivate()
    {
        $db = new Db( $this->db_name );
        $db->delete_table();

        $option = new Option( $this->option_name );
        $option->remove();
    }
}

class Db
{
    protected $db_name;

    public function __construct( $db_name )
    {
        $this->db_name = $db_name;
    }

    public function create_table()
    {
        // install table, for this demonstration, we use an option
        return \add_option( $this->db_name, 'exists' );
    }

    public function delete_table()
    {
        // uninstall table
        return \delete_option( $this->db_name );
    }
}

class Option
{
    protected $option_name;

    public function __construct( $option_name )
    {
        $this->option_name = $option_name;
    }

    public function add()
    {
        // add option
        return \add_option( $this->option_name, 'exists' );
    }

    public function remove()
    {
        // delete option
        return \delete_option( $this->option_name );
    }
}
```

You can test the success with a second plugin:

```
add_action( 'admin_footer', function() {

    $db     = get_option( 'wpse_db', 'missing' );
    $option = get_option( 'wpse_option', 'missing' );

    print "<code>\$db = $db, \$option = $option</code>";
});
```

Some links for further reading:

- [Namespaces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)
- [Closures (Lambda functions)](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)
- [MVC Pattern](http://phpmaster.com/the-mvc-pattern-and-php-1/) (there is no View in my answer)
- [Front Controllers](http://phpmaster.com/front-controller-pattern-1/)

Comment: [Namespaces and lambda functions](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2496/the-namespace-wpse) at once, welcome to 2013!

Comment: @brasofilo Actually, these are [features from 2009](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.3.0).

Comment: @brasofilo Welcome to WordPress 4.6!

Comment: @StephenHarris, it arrived earlier than expected :) toscho, on the other hand, took longer than expected :P

Comment: Great!! Thank you so much for your help. That's beyond my capabilities so I'm going to digest your code carefully and learn from it.

Comment: @ahnkee See my update: I have added some links. They should help understanding my code. If you have any further questions, just ask. :)

Comment: @toscho Once again, thank you! I'm excited to be learning new things :)